# Is Set an autonomous category?

Tags: category-theory

Is the category of sets an autonomous category? If not, how can it be proved? What would be the dual of a set?

What is the relevant bibliography for autonomous categories?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A monoidal category is called left autonomous (or rigid) if every object $X$ has a left dual $X^*$, i.e. such that $\hom(X^* \otimes Y , Z) = \hom(Y, X \otimes Z)$ naturally in $Y,Z$. It follows in particular that $\hom(X^*,-) \cong \hom(1,X \otimes -)$. If $X \otimes -$ preserves colimits (for example in the closed case) and $1$ is finitely presentable, it follows that also $X^*$ is finitely presentable. In the symmetric case $(X^*)^*=X$, so that every dualizable object is finitely presentable. This shows that autonomous categories tend to be "small", and the category of sets is not autonomous.

In fact, if in a cartesian category $C$ an object $X$ has a left dual $X^*$, then we get $\star = \hom(X^* \otimes 1,1)=\hom(1,X)$, i.e. there is exactly one morphism $1 \to X$. It follows that $1$ is the only dualizable object of $\mathsf{Set}$.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are taking the ordinary cartesian product to be your monoidal product, the answer is no.  For Set to be  *-autonomous, we would need $Hom(A\times B,C^*) \cong Hom(A,(B\times C)^*)$ naturally isomorphic.  If all these sets are finite, taking cardinalities we have $|A\times B|^{|C|} = |A|^{|B\times C|}$.  This equation is false for many finite sets $A,B,C$.

Comment: You seem to use that $C^*$ and $C$ have the same cardinality?

Comment: Ah yes sorry.  To correct this I would end up basically having to do something as in your last edit.